# What's the correct way to specify replacement of any of a list of substrings with one value

Tags: regex, teradata

I'm trying to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` in Teradata to replace portions of a text field's value with a space. I'd like to just build one large target list rather than nesting multiple `REGEXP_REPLACE`s inside of each other, but thus far I haven't found an example that shows how to specify multiple target substrings.

To give an example, if I have the value `Insulin Aspart Inj 100 Unit/ML` I want the target portion of the regex to target `Inj`, `Unit`, & `ML` so that at the end the `REGEXP_REPLACE` (when I include the `0-9\` token in the target list and a wrapping `OREPLACE` to swap double spaces with single space) should pare my example string to `Insulin Aspart`.

Currently, I've tried

- `OREPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(DWI.GPI_Generic_Name)), '[0-9 INJ ]', ' ',1,0,'i'),'  ', ' ')`
- `OREPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(DWI.GPI_Generic_Name)), '[0-9| INJ ]', ' ',1,0,'i'),'  ', ' ')`
- `OREPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(DWI.GPI_Generic_Name)), '[0-9|' INJ ']', ' ',1,0,'i'),'  ', ' ')`

As well as a couple other permutations along those lines. And I know those examples don't include ML or Unit; I didn't add them since I couldn't get the INJ part working correctly.

The ones that run strip the letters in "INJ" though, rather then the string "INJ" each time (when the particular permutation is executable).

Ideally, if it were the case that the target portion of `REGEXP_REPLACE` was a comma delimited list, where wrapping the target with double quotes specified target the combination of letters rather the the individual letters, my code would look like this:

`OREPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(DWI.GPI_Generic_Name)), '[0-9," INJ "," UNIT","ML",\]', ' ',1,0,'i'),'  ', ' ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify multiple patterns using `|`:

```
RegExp_Replace(Upper(Trim(DWI.GPI_Generic_Name)), '(Inj|Unit|[0-9]+|ML|/)', '',1,0,'i')
```

If you replace the match with an empty string there's no need for oReplace.

Comment: Thanks! One other case that caused a hiccup when I started expanding your pattern. If the substring contains a special character (a `-` in the case I've seen so far) how would I handle that?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. For those with the same question, simply escape the character. Ex. `AUTO\-INJECTOR` in my regex would remove "AUTO-INJECTOR"